# Pegar valores de um Array de Input em React

Tags: javascript, react

Estou adicionando dois novos `input`s para cada produto que está me retornando da `<li>`.

Nesses novos inputs estou colocando um `onChange` para pegar o que for digitado e colocar no meu `useState`, mas estou tendo dificuldade, pois ele coloca dentro deste array qualquer alteração no meu input, seja uma tecla ou outra. Sem falar que posso ter vários inputs iguais de acordo com o número de produtos que volta.

Minha dúvida é, teria alguma outra maneira de fazer isto?

Estou tentando achar soluções e fazer isto a quatro dias e está complicado.

```
const [quantidadeUsada, SetQuantidadeUsada] = useState([]);
const [numeroLote, setNumeroLote] = useState([]);

const onChangeQtdUsada = (ev) => {
  const { value } = ev.target;
  SetQuantidadeUsada([...quantidadeUsada, value]);
  //console.log(quantidadeUsada);
}

const onChangeNrmLote = (ev) => {
  const {value} = ev.target;
  setNumeroLote([...numeroLote, value]);
  //console.log(numeroLote);
}

return (
  <ul className="prods-list">
    {prods.map(prod => (
    <li key={prod.modelo}>
      <label htmlFor="modelo">Modelo</label>
      <input name="modelo" type="text" value={prod.modelo} disabled/>
      <label htmlFor="quantidadeDisponível">Quantidade Disponível</label>
      <input name="quantidadeDisponível" type="text" value={prod.quantidadeComprada} disabled/>

        //AQUI ESTOU ADICIONANDO OS DOIS INPUTS
      <label htmlFor="quantidadeUsada">Quantidade Aplicada</label>
      <input name="quantidadeUsada" type="text" onChange={onChangeQtdUsada} placeholder="Em metros" />
      <label htmlFor="numeroLote">Número do Lote</label>
      <input name="numeroLote" type="text" onChange={onChangeNrmLote} />
    </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Estes inputs serão salvos em uma tabela do BD juntamente com o produto retornado:

```
const id_ProdNfe = prods.map(prod => {
  return prod.produtoNfe_id;
});

for (var i = 0; i < id_ProdNfe.length; i++) {
  const responseProd = await api.post('/consumidor/produto', {
    quantidadeUsada: quantidadeUsada[i],
    numeroLote: numeroLote[i],
    fk_consumidor_id: consumidor_id,
    fk_produtoNfe_id: id_ProdNfe[i]
  });
  console.log(responseProd);
}
```

Comment: Quando colocar o código de um componente aqui no Stack Overflow, sugiro não separá-lo em diferentes partes, isso dificulta o entendimento. Quando necessário, omita o código não-relacionado, mas não "bagunce" o código.

Comment: Do jeito que está aí, toda vez que o evento onChange é invocado, adiciona um novo elemento ao array, mas isso vc já deve ter percebido. Se o que você quer é alterar um elemento específico do array `quantidadeUsada`, você deveria passar para `onChangeQtdUsada()` um argumento que identificasse o indice que você deseja alterar.  Duas opções seriam o index do callback do `prods.map` ou a `key` `prop` da lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui pegar o valor de cada input em especifico, vou colocar a resolução.

```js
const [quantidadeUsada, SetQuantidadeUsada] = useState([]);
const [numeroLote, setNumeroLote] = useState([]);

const onChangeQtdUsada = (e, index) => {
  quantidadeUsada[index] = e.target.value;
  SetQuantidadeUsada([...quantidadeUsada]);
  //console.log(quantidadeUsada);
}

const onChangeNrmLote = (e, index) => {
  numeroLote[index] = e.target.value;
  setNumeroLote([...numeroLote]);
  //console.log(numeroLote);
}
```

```html
return (
<ul className="prods-list">
  {prods.map(prod => (
  <li key={prod.modelo}>
    <label htmlFor="modelo">Modelo</label>
    <input name="modelo" type="text" value={prod.modelo} disabled/>
    <label htmlFor="quantidadeDisponível">Quantidade Disponível</label>
    <input name="quantidadeDisponível" type="text" value={prod.quantidadeComprada} disabled/> //AQUI
    <div key={index}>
      <label htmlFor={`quantidadeUsada-${index+1}`}>Quantidade Aplicada</label>
      <input name="quantidadeUsada" type="text" id={`quantidadeUsada-${index+1}`} onChange={(e)=> onChangeQtdUsada(e, index)} placeholder="Em metros"/>

      <label htmlFor={`numeroLote-${index+1}`}>Número do Lote</label>
      <input name="numeroLote" type="text" id={`numeroLote-${index+1}`} onChange={(e)=> onChangeNrmLote(e, index)} placeholder="Ou Número da Nfe"/>
    </div>
  </li>
  ))}
</ul>
);
```

Agora estou pegando cada posição do meu input com o index e colocando em um array.

Answer (score -2):

No caso do `onChange` você teria que passar uma função anônima para receber esse valor do `input`:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

<input onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value) }/>
```

Não precisaria passar uma função para pegar o valor do `input`, o próprio `setState` já é uma função.